# Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS ks.cfg

Tags: boot, server, partitioning

I am in the process of creating an automated Server Install using ks.cfg the entire process work fine expect for the formatting and partitioning of the disk.

I want the installer to automatically proceed by formatting and paritioning the drive no matter the status. Currently if there is an existing file system the install pauses and asks you to confirm the over write. Here is the relevant piece of the KS.cfg

```
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
#Disk partitioning information
part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow --asprimary
```

Here is the menu in question:

[image]

I tried adding `--y` to the end of the part command as a guess and that didn't work. This is probably pretty simple but I have not been able to find the syntax to accomplish and I'm pretty inexperienced with Ubuntu / Linux in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help guys it got me going down the right path and narrowed down my googling to finally get me the answer. In order to answer these prompts you must utilize preseed commands for partman I added the lines below and now my KS.cfg now looks like this:

## Clear the Master Boot Record

zerombr yes

## Partition clearing information

clearpart --all --initlabel

## Disk partitioning information

part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow --asprimary

## Skip question(s) about not having swap partition or overwriting the existing FS

preseed partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true

preseed partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true

preseed partman/confirm boolean true

preseed partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

preseed --owner partman-basicfilesystems partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false.

The results is that my Install media will now wipe the drive and create a new File System without any prompts no matter the state. Hope this helps others

Comment: I have added the preseed command but still its prompting to confirm? Does the placement of the command matters?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but piping yes with part command may work. Try both of these below one by one and tell me whether any of them works or not.

**part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow --asprimary | yes**

**yes | part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow --asprimary**

Answer (score 0):

I had this a while ago on a CentOS ks config:

This is an extract of how I think I fixed it.

```
zerombr
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
clearpart --all --linux --drives=sda
```

Notice the lack of yes after zerombr, I dont know if ignoredisk is required but I had it there.